# return empty string using sshpass authentication

Tags: php, linux, ssh, shell-exec

I am new to Linux-SA server automation tool environment. I'm trying to authenticate `sshpass` as follows:

In a linux environment, I use the following code in terminal and getting list of files properly:

```
sshpass -p Password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@localhost "ls /root"
```

But if I try to get the result from PHP as follows it returns an empty string:

```
shell_exec('sshpass -p Password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@localhost "ls /root"');
```

Comment: If you can't figure it out you might want to try http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ . sshpass does password auth as keyboard-interactive without presenting the user with actual prompts. phpseclib does this as well. Check the examples for details. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting to this server through ssh first time, you need to do this one time manual. So RSA key was added to known hosts. Got same problem. And this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/function.exec.php). Keep in mind that if `ssh` fails and you might expect its error message in php, ssh prints this to stderr, php only gets stdout and this is empty. Just redirect stderr to stdout by adding `2>&1` to the end of the command. As the [manpage of sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) states, **Security Considerations** should be understood when using -p option.

```
$ssh_host = "localhost";
$ssh_port = "22";
$ssh_user = "root";
$ssh_pass = "Password";
$command = "ls /root";
$connection = "/usr/bin/sshpass -p $ssh_pass /usr/bin/ssh -p $ssh_port -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null $ssh_user@$ssh_host";
$output = exec($connection." ".$command." 2>&1");
echo "Output: $output";
```

Answer (score 0):

are you calling PHP in a webpage?

is sshpass in the path? how about using a full path?

e.g.

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/sshpass -p Password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@localhost "ls /root"');
```

*you need to work out where your sshpass is

also, you might want to investigate ssh keys instead of putting passwords like this in your code - it could be a security problem.. (actually i don't know what you're doing, you're sshing to localhost, but maybe you're just testing?)

Comment: Thanks Jon Soong,
Yes we are testing, but we need to check whether entered password correct or not, one more thing i need to access few file which is located in root file system from our application. note: our application has seperate file system under root.

Answer (score 0):

Please take the output of above command in some variable and display that variable.
eg:

$output = shell_exec('sshpass -p Password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@localhost "ls /root"');

echo $output

This will definitely show you the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission issue between sshpass and apache user (www-data in my case).

Include this line on sudoers (/etc/sudoers)

`www-data  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sshpass`   -> change to sshpass location at your system and Apache user.

And include "sudo" before sshpass

```
shell_exec('sudo /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p Password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@localhost "ls /root"');
```